# JasperReports: Empty resultset in subreport returns null variable to main report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a subreport in *JR* report which returns a value to main report. If the result in *subreport* is empty then the variable return is null and hence all the calculation perform on this return value goes as null. I tried many things like

```java
$V{ReturnValue} == null ? 0 : $V{ReturnValue}
$V{ReturnValue}.toString().equals(null) ?.....
and many other stupid things but all in vein.
```

I read many posts on many websites specially on *SO* but no one has ever answered this question except one which is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo! By the Grace of GOD, I made a great answer to my own question. Posting it as it may help someone in future.

```
1) I changed my Simple SQL Query with a MySQL stored procedure as.
```

My Stored Procedure as

```
BEGIN
SET @m = '0';
SELECT x.*, y.* FROM 
     (select 1 as "ID", @m:=acc as "Account", Amount from tbl_reports) x
     right JOIN 
     (SELECT if(@m='0',0,1) as "IDU") y
ON y.IDU = x.ID;
END
```

In IReport, I declared my variable as

```
$F{IDU}==1?$F{Amount}:0
```

In this way, it now shows 0.00 instead of null. What it actually does is that it

**Explanation**

1) It sets a @m Variable with default value of '0'

2) Then if there it finds any row for x table it replace @m with new Account Name

3) when it comes to y table, it checks whether @m has been changed, if changed then put 1

4) In IReport, our variable expression says that if IDU has 1 its mean there is a row from resultset and if 0 then it means that there was no row and put 0.